# How to cache nextjs (getStaticProps) request?

Tags: javascript, next.js

How can I cache the server side fetch request? I am running the same fetch thousands of times this means, once for each page, but the only parameter is the locale.

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({  locale }) => {
  const accountManager = await getAccountManager(locale); 
  return {
    props: {
      accountManager: accountManager
    },
    revalidate: 120,
  };
};
export async function getAccountManagerByLocale(
  tld = 'com'
): Promise<AccountManager> {
  const res = await fetch(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CRM_API_URL + '/account-manager/?locale=' + tld,
    {
      headers: {
        accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'accept-language': 'en',
      },
    }
  );
  const accountManagersList = await res.json();
  return accountManagersList[0];
}
```

P.S.:

- Nextjs fetch polyfill seems to ignore the Cache-Policy header
- React-Query seems too big for an ecommerce (since the client only fetch data for products when filtering) , I'm hardcoding an account managers json on the server for now only to not increase the bundle size that much